# Delete occurrences of an integer from data

Tags: matlab

These are just little part of my data:

```
40

-0.020558 -0.33809 2.34418 1

0.492172 0.671646 18752 0

-0.0262787 -0.286294 2.37592 1

0.490128 0.643408 19000 0

40

-0.020526 -0.338069 2.3442 1

0.492184 0.671634 18752 0

-0.0262508 -0.286282 2.37596 1

0.490138 0.643399 19000 0

40

-0.0204959 -0.338048 2.34421 1

0.492196 0.671622 18752 0

-0.026225 -0.286269 2.376 1

0.490148 0.64339 19008 0
```

I want to store them in a matrix without the **40**.

How can I delete all occurrences of the integer 40 in one go in Matlab?

Comment: How is your data stored? In a file? In a existing matrix or vector in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [*`dlmread`*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) to read entire file as Matrix say `M`, and then remove row which has `40` in it

```
>> M=dlmread('filename.txt', ' ');
>> M(any(M'==40),:) =[];
```

Comment: Can you explain more detail? I have to read first? What's in ' '

Comment: @KanjaePark Read the documentation of `dlmread`, `' '` is a delimiter which in our case is space, you can use `'\t'` if the numbers are separated by tabs

Comment: I just use M=dlmread('filename.txt',' '); |
But they comment 'file could not be opened because : No such file or directory' How can I solve this TT

Comment: Oh It's going well !! just wait plz